# How to call custom functions of Gem(By adding any attr_accessor/Method/Callbacks in model) whenever we run listing/find query from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mobility

I am working on developing my custom gem which will be providing translations based on given parameters. I have used `mobility gem` https://github.com/shioyama/mobility as a dependency of my custom gem.

I have prepared a common function in our custom gem which will giving us desired result based on given params(We are using mobility gem to translate records). I am finding a solution to call custom gem common function Whenever any find query or listing query gets called from controller.

This means if i call center listing query `Center.all` in center controller index method, It should go to custom gem common function after fetching data from database. Our common function will be translating records based given params and return result with translations. This same should be happened with find query also. Any idea how such things can be achieved by adding any attr_accessor/method/callback functions in model? Based on our added method/callback function, it will decide whether it should go in custom gem or not.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
def index
    @centers = Center.all
    # Here when i call, Center.all, it should go to common function of my custom gem with data and return back.
    render json: {status: 'success', data: @centers}, status: :ok
end
```

if i call listing query `Center.all` in center controller index method, It should go to custom gem common function after fetching data from database. Our common function will be translating records based given params and return result with translations. This same should be happened with find query also.

Comment: Have you considered adding a custom scope to your model, instead of calling `Center.all`?

Comment: Although it possible to patch the ActiveRecord `.all` method, there's a simpler way ... make a plain ruby method somewhere that takes the query as an argument, and does something with it.

Comment: You can override the finders. 

`class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.all
    TransformGem.translate(super)
  end
end`
I'd might argue this is not a good idea because it's hiding the work, rather than being explicit in the controller about what's happening. It depends on why you're doing this. Rails already has great i18n support baked in.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just override all in your model class.

For example I have a Tag model.

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :run
  def self.all
    puts "before"
    puts super
    puts "after"
  end
end
```

But if you want to do this for a number of models it might be cleaner to use Module#prepend

If I create a Module with some local overrides.

```
module LocalOverrides
  def all
    puts "before"
    puts super
    puts "after"
  end
end
```

I can also use prepend to override all and still be able to call the original `all` method.

```
Tag.singleton_class.send :prepend, LocalOverrides
```

In both cases you would get the desired result, the ability to "wrap" the all method with your own code.

```
Tag.all 
#=> before
#=> #<Tag::ActiveRecord_Relation ... 
#=> after
```